# C# WPF Textboxbinding: using exception and want after a empty textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

i wrote a WPF userapplication for some administration taks and finaly im ready ... up to one last problem:

I have 2 TextBox controlls and i dont want to make it possible for the user to fill both at the same time so i did this:

```
      private string versichertennummerAlt = "";
            public string VersichertennummerAlt
            {
                get { return versichertennummerAlt; }
                set
                {
                    if (Versichertennummer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        versichertennummerAlt = "";
                        OnPropertyChanged("VersichertennummerAlt");
                        throw new ArgumentException("Es kann nur die neue ODER die alte Versichertennummer eingegeben werden.\n Eine von beiden löschen.");                  
                    }
........
}
}
```

It works how it should, and i get the exception and the string is "" if the user try to fill both at the same time, but somehow the textbox is still showing the last pressed key, even the property is "".

What am i doing wrong?
Or how can i make sure the TextBox dosnt show anything after the exception?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: why don't you disable the second textbox control when the first for example is filled ? then the user can't even try to write in the second

Comment: I was thinking about it, but it wouldnt fit to the layout of the application. (if i click in the DataGrid, one of the fields get filled and i guess it would not lock good if 2 textboxes all day long swtich from enabled to disabled)

Comment: Why not set the IsReadOnly property?.:) It won't affect the layout and the styling of your textboxes.

Comment: you're setting the private variable to ="" this wont affect the UI because there is no OnPropertyChanged Event `versichertennummerAlt = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use exceptions in this way unless you are catching it somewhere and dealing with it. Entering text in a text box should never be fatal. That aside, I think doing as was suggested in the comments is a good idea, that is, make one text box `IsEnabled="False"` if there is text in the other and vise-versa:

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Key="TextBoxA"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextBoxAEnabled}"
                Text="{Binding TextA}"/>
<TextBox x:Key="TextBoxB"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextBoxBEnabled}"
            Text="{Binding TextB}"/>
```

CS:

```
private string textA;
public string TextA
{
    get { return textA; }
    set
    {
        if (textA == value)
            return;
        textA = value;
        this.IsTextBoxBEnabled = String.IsNullOrEmpty(textA);
        OnPropertyChanged("TextA");
    }
}

private bool isTextBoxAEnabled;
public bool IsTextBoxAEnabled
{
    get { return isTextBoxAEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (isTextBoxAEnabled == value)
            return;
        isTextBoxAEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsTextBoxAEnabled");
    }
}
```

You will also need to do this for `TextBoxB`. The above should disable one when the other has text...

**Edit**

To address your comment reguarding a red borer etc. you want to implement `IDataErrorInfo`

```
#region IDataErrorInfo Implementation.
/// <summary>
/// Access to the error.
/// </summary>
string IDataErrorInfo.Error
{
    get { return String.Empty; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the validation error.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property to validate.</param>
/// <returns>The error information as a string.</returns>
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return ExecuteValidation(); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Run validation routines.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Error message.</returns>
private string ExecuteValidation()
{
    // Put validation for the other TextBox here.
    return String.Empty;
}
#endregion // IDataErrorInfo Implementation.
```

used like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                        NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

Then when the validation fails you will get your error highlighting.

I hope this helps.

---

*Note. for the above to work you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.*

Comment: Mhm i guess i just do it without the exception and make it impossible to write while the other box is filled :) The problem is, i wanted a hint for the user that he only can use one of the boxes at a time (while hes trying .. like a red border or what ever). but thx ;)

Comment: Then you want to implement `IDataErrorInfo` on the text box.

Comment: Uhh yes, i guess thats what i want ;) mhm and can you maybe tell me how to use it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try use in textbox binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

I try to realize this situation like it:

```
private string versichertennummer = "";
    public string Versichertennummer
    {
        get { return versichertennummer; }
        set 
        {
            if (VersichertennummerAlt.Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Es kann nur die neue ODER die alte Versichertennummer     eingegeben werden.\n Eine von beiden löschen.");
                //OnPropertyChanged("Versichertennummer");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                versichertennummer = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private string versichertennummerAlt = "";
    public string VersichertennummerAlt
    {
        get { return versichertennummerAlt; }
        set
            {
                if (Versichertennummer.Length > 0)
                {
                    //versichertennummerAlt = "";
                    //OnPropertyChanged("VersichertennummerAlt");
                    MessageBox.Show("Es kann nur die neue ODER die alte Versichertennummer eingegeben werden.\n Eine von beiden löschen.");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    versichertennummerAlt = value;
                }
            }
    }
```

And i didn't get situation like you have.